# Exit Google Chrome from terminal

Tags: shell-script, kill, exit, chrome

Is there a way to cause `google-chrome` to quit, from the terminal, besides using `killall google-chrome`? 
I would like to be able to close it from a script without killing it.

Comment: What is wrong with kill?

Comment: @Zoredache That it results in different behavior from exiting, and that Chrome uses multiple processes, one of which (the sandbox) is setuid root.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perhaps [`wmctrl`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) could be of some assistance. You could use the `-c` option that closes a window gracefully:

```
wmctrl -c chrome
```

The string `chrome` is matched against the window titles. Note that the window might not close if some message pops-up (e.g. when you have multiple tabs open).

Comment: This option works flawless, but it required the installation of `wmctrl`.

Comment: wmctrl cannot close system tray "Chrome Apps". `pkill -o chrome` does though.

Comment: Only works on X Window Manager.  Not a future proof solution

Answer (score 35):

This command exits the chrome process tree gracefully, in all window managers:

```
pkill --oldest chrome
```

or if you prefer:

```
/usr/bin/pkill --oldest --signal TERM -f chrome
```

Details:

- gracefully means: avoid seeing “Google Chrome didn't shut down correctly. To repoen ...” next time chrome starts
- chrome browser (e.g. version 39.0.2171.95) traps and gracefully handles `SIGTERM`
- signal a single process, the root of chrome’s process tree, hence `--oldest`
- `SIGTERM` is the same as signal `15`, hence `--signal TERM`, or just leave it out since `SIGTERM` is the default signal
- `wmctrl` works with Unity and some others but it does not work with all window managers
- `wmctrl -c` closes one window at a time so to close all chrome windows you would need something like `while wmctrl -c 'Google Chrome'; do sleep 0.2; done`

Comment: I assume I am using an old version of pkill as `--oldest` is not an option: using `-o` works.

Comment: the `-f` argument to pkill is not working for me.  I have some other processes running as root that happen to have the word chrome in their command lines, so I just get permission denied.  Without the `-f`, it works perfectly though.

Comment: This still makes me see 'didn't shut down corrently'

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04, how could I make this to be executed immediately after triggering a restart or a shutdown?.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
killall --quiet --signal 15 -- chrome
```

Note that I'm using a rather verbose command to keep it readable in the code, of course you could also issue:

```
killall -q -15 chrome
```

Answer (score 1):

On `Mac OS X`, use this instead

```
pkill -a -i "Google Chrome"
```

What it does is to look for a Google Chrome process, and kill all of its parent processes as well.

From the pkill manual

```
    -a          Include process ancestors in the match list.  By default, the
                current pgrep or pkill process and all of its ancestors are
                excluded (unless -v is used).
    -i          Ignore case distinctions in both the process table and the
                supplied pattern.
```

As per @keith-cascio ' s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174451/29720), you can try to kill the oldest process instead. Note that this did not work for me.

```
pkill -o -i "Google Chrome"
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
kill -3 <pid_of_chrome>
```

This will send a "QUIT" signal to chrome, which, depending on your window manager, will be what it is usually sent when asked to close.

Comment: This acts just like `kill` or `killall` where Chrome sees it as a crash, and asking to restore.

Comment: try 15 instead of 3, then

Comment: Actually, `SIGQUIT` is not usually sent to applications when asked to close (I don't know any WMs that do this). `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` is the standard.

Comment: @blacklemon67 `kill -15 <pid_of_chrome>` did what I was looking for. But, `google-chrome` has multiple pids and it took a few tried to actually get the right one.

Answer (score -1):

For Ubuntu just simply enter:

exit google-chrome

Comment: The `exit` verb takes an optional status _value_, not a command