# How to kill chromium command line over ssh?

Tags: command-line, raspbian, kill, chrome

I have a chromium running on a raspberry pi showing some monitor stats. Sometimes, the startup fails opening the relevant tabs and hence I want to restart chromium. Yet running:

```
killall chromium-browser
```

only kills the *tabs*, showing me the "oh snap" information. I want the entire chromium to shutdown.

Running the same command again yields in:

```
killall chromium-browser 
chromium-browser: no process found
```

even though I see the oh snap tab.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To exit Chromium gracefully use the following command:

```
pkill -o chromium
```

If you do not specify the "-o" ("--oldest") flag you might see the "Chromium didn't shut down correctly" pop-up next time you start Chromium. Because signal will be received by all chromium processes instead of just the main one.

Based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174451).

Comment: Made my day. Thx. I don't know why it behaves better that `pkill -HUP chromium` which display popups for many crashing extensions when exiting chromium. I keep your solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
pkill chromium
```

did the trick .