# How to gracefully kill (like normal close) Google Chrome (over SSH)?

Tags: chrome, kill, signals, reboot, ubuntu-mate

I am running a "TV laptop" - just a low-powered laptop connected to a TV with one single purpose, to run a live TV stream from Google Chrome on Ubuntu MATE 20.04.2 LTS.

The first thing I noticed when rebooting this machine with just `reboot` over `ssh`, was that:

> "Chrome didn't shut down correctly."

which is an exact transcript of the bubble message.

Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341159/how-to-kill-chromium-command-line-over-ssh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my testing, it appears, that `HUP` or signal `1`, like `pkill -HUP chrome` does lead to the same message, but **issuing signal `2` to Chrome is a valid solution**.

I, originally, have thought, that such a solution could be generic to all GUI programs. However, it likely is not. I'm, however, pleased to see this simple solution, which is:

```
pkill -INT chrome
```

or

```
pkill -2 chrome
```

one and the same command, just the first is the name of the signal instead of its number.

---

If we apply this solution over SSH with for example using an alias `ssh-tv` to connect to that laptop, we could define something very similar to this to achieve our reboot without that message:

```
alias reboot-tv-laptop='ssh-tv -t "pkill -2 chrome; sleep 5s; reboot"'
```

Note, that there may be many and maybe even better ways of achieving the same goal. This works for me personally.